# How to bind controls to either a list element or a property on a class?

Tags: mvvm, view, data-binding, maui, viewmodel

This one is mostly for curiosity, though I can see where I might need this knowledge in the near future. Let's say, for the sake of this discussion, that I have six different labels on a single page. Now, to bind them using a ViewModel I can do so very simply with Bindable Properties. The following code works, and I will ask my question afterwards:

The Home Page xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             x:Class="TestBed.Mobile.HomePage"
             Title="HomePage">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label Text="{Binding Label1}" FontSize="24" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        <Label Text="{Binding Label2}" FontSize="24" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        <Label Text="{Binding Label3}" FontSize="24" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        <Label Text="{Binding Label4}" FontSize="24" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        <Label Text="{Binding Label5}" FontSize="24" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        <Label Text="{Binding Label6}" FontSize="24" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

The HomePage code-behind:

```
using TestBed.Client.Core;
using TestBed.Client.Core.ViewModels;

namespace TestBed.Mobile;

public partial class HomePage : ContentPage
{
    public HomePage(HomeViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = viewModel;
    }
}
```

And finally, the ViewModel:

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;

namespace TestBed.Client.Core.ViewModels
{
    public partial class HomeViewModel : ObservableObject
    {

        [ObservableProperty]
        String _label1 = "First Label";

        [ObservableProperty]
        String _label2 = "Second Label";

        [ObservableProperty]
        String _label3 = "Third Label";

        [ObservableProperty]
        String _label4 = "Fourth Label";

        [ObservableProperty]
        String _label5 = "Fifth Label";

        [ObservableProperty]
        String _label6 = "Sixth Label";

        public HomeViewModel()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

That works fine, but I can see situations arising where the data might be organized differently. For example, instead of the six bindable properties in the ViewModel, I might have the six labels loaded into a List. So the ViewModel might look like this:

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;

namespace TestBed.Client.Core.ViewModels
{
    public partial class HomeViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        List<String> listOfLabelText = new List<string>();

        public HomeViewModel()
        {
            // Some logic to populate the list
        }
    }
}
```

In that example, I'd want to bind ListOfLabelText[0] to Label1, and so forth. Conceptually, something like this:

```
<Label Text="{Binding ListOfLabelText[0]}" />
```

Or, as another possibility, the six label texts could be stored in a class, and I'd want to bind each label control to the correct property of that class.

What I haven't yet been able to figure out is how to bind the Label Control on the View to the appropriate list or class element. This kind of thing seems like something there'd be a way to do, but so far my Googling hasn't located anything on point. I'd hate to think that my only option is to copy the data out of the list or class and into individual bindable properties in the View Model.

Finally, I understand the principle of binding a list to a dropdown or ListView, but that's not what I want. As a building block for future development, I want to know how to bind individual elements in a list or individual properties in a class to specific controls on the view... assuming it is, in fact, possible.

Any suggestions are welcome.

**EDIT:** What I ended up doing was still MVVM friendly, and that is to dodge the issue of finding the perfect xaml binding and instead move the control bindings into the code-behind. Binding controls to a list of classes is dirt-simple in C#. I have the sample piece I was working on up and purring right now, and I think I just might be starting to get comfortable with this whole .NET Maui and MVVM stuff. (grin)

Comment: “{Binding ListOfLabelText[0]}” or use a BindableLayout

Comment: Never heard of bindable layout... I will give it a look.

And thanks for the note on binding to a list... I must have had a typo in my code when I tried that earlier, because it worked fine when I tried it again.